# How to implement role based access to Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, role-base-authorization

We develop ServerLess Application based on Azure Functions.

What is the best way to implement Authentication/Authorization based on User Roles? The authentication should not depend on 3rd parties like AAD, Facebook, etc. This is custom auth.

It should be something like we have in ASP.NET MVC/WEB.API using Authorize Attributes with Roles.

Comment: I guess you could use the ASP.NET Identity and/or OWIN classes yourself to create the tokens and then check them. It's probably gonna be a lot of work, but currently I'm not aware of an easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Akos said, you can create an Azure Function Proxy. It will receive the token, validate and if it's ok, route to the proper Azure Function. It worth a mention that it will require some coding in order to make it work properly.